# is it possible to insert a gzipped string (Json string) as a varchar in postgres

Tags: postgresql

Will I run into any weird byte sequence if I attempt to store a binary (a gzipped Json string) in a varchar column. Or Should I base64 encode it after compressing.

Comment: Why would you do that? Store binary data as `bytea`, store json data as `json(b)`. Don't store either of them as `varchar`.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, thats fair. Lets just say in a hypothetical scenario, if I am to store it in varchar, do you foresee any issues?

Comment: I know the postgres varchar/text does not support a null character - \0.  I don't know if it's possible that the zip string will contain the null string.  If so, varchar will not work

Comment: @so-random-dude It probably depends on the chosen string encoding? But I can't really tell, and that alone would make me avoid `varchar` and use the proper type for the intended purpose.

Comment: Thanks folks, appreciate your response